# Change bar color depending on value

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm using chart-js/ng2-charts for an angular 2 app.

I can display a bar graph, but at the moment, all the bars are the same color. I'd like to have a different color depending on the value.

Can that be done?

Comment: Are you talking about native dynamic backgroundColor? I'm not sure about that, but it seems like it'd be pretty straightforward to create some logic for a variable representing the the [backgroundColor property value](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-colors).

Comment: Yes, I have it sussed out now. Haven't looked at it before and it needed it sorted quickly, but yep, sorted now. Will post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 3):

After you create your chart, you can use the following function to loop through the dataset and change the color depending on the data value.

In this example, if the value is above a 50, the color changes to red.

```
var colorChangeValue = 50; //set this to whatever is the deciding color change value
var dataset = myChart.data.datasets[0];
for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
  if (dataset.data[i] > colorChangeValue) {
    dataset.backgroundColor[i] = chartColors.red;
  }
}
myChart.update();
```

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6d0jsyxu/1/